# Handling 'Combining Diacritical Marks' in filenames with R

Tags: r, unicode

I have several hundred filenames with ['Combining Diacritical Marks'](http://www.codetable.net/Group/combining-diacritical-marks) ([Unicode General Category Mn](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Mn)).  When I use the `list.files()` function, I cannot get R to read from or open these files as R converts the file name with the 'Combining Diacritical Marks' such as `\u301` and `\u308` into `\xb4` and `\xa8`, respectively.  The result is a different filename that the system cannot find. How do you prevent R from substituting these characters?

Applying the `gsub()` function over the list of filenames to replace the stand alone acute accent with the combining acute accent (i.e. `filenames <- gsub("A´", "Á", filenames)` changes the "A´" into the single unicode character "Á", not the double unicode characters "Á" which is not the same thing, and therefore the system cannot find a file with that name. (paste into a text editor to see that they are not the same.)

Even passing the double unicode characters "Á" into `print("Á")` and running from  the console returns the single unicode character "Á". However, `print("A\u301")` returns the correct double unicode characters "Á". Whereas `gsub("A´", "A\u301", "A´")` returns `"A´"`.

It appears that the [`stringi::stri_trans_nf*()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringi/versions/1.1.5/topics/stri_trans_nfc) functions are a possible solution, but I am not sure how to use with the `list.files()` or `gsub()` functions to return a list of filenames that can then be interpreted correctly by the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself.

Used the following to change the character vector of filenames into the correct system representation with the 'Combining Acute Accent' `\u301` and the 'Combining Diaeresis' `\u308`.

```
oldnames <- list.files(pattern = "*.pdf", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
library(stringi)
oldnames <- unlist(lapply(oldnames, stri_replace_all_regex, "´", "\u301"))
oldnames <- unlist(lapply(oldnames, stri_replace_all_regex, "¨", "\u308"))
```

Then make a new character vector of filenames that do not have the combining diacritical marks.

```
newnames <- oldnames
newnames <- unlist(lapply(newnames, stri_replace_all_regex, "\u301", ""))
newnames <- unlist(lapply(newnames, stri_replace_all_regex, "\u308", ""))
```

Then rename the files with the new filenames.

```
file.rename(oldnames,newnames)
```

At least now I can handle the files in R as usual.